# Excel assigning different dollar values and adding them

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am creating a spreadsheet and I want to assign different dollar values and add them together.  For example I want B to represent 10.00 per hour for each hour I type in then I want C to represent 15.00 per hour for each hour I type in then I want D to be the total of B and C.  By the time it is set up I would like to only have to place the number of hours in each column and have excel calculate the total.

Answer (score 1):

A simple formula will work, filled down

`D1` = `(10*B1)+(15*C1)` and format it to dollars.